# My EC2 AWS Public DNS url (ubuntu serve) is being directed to a different page and a directory is not showing up

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, laravel-4

I set up a virtual server through AWS using an EC2 instance (ubuntu).  I am trying to get my Laravel project up and running.  I have set everything up, and installed apache, php, and mcrypt.  I also used SFTP to upload my Laravel project to the /var/www folder on the server.

Right now, when I visit the public DNS url: `ec2-**-***-***-***.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

It takes me to the "Apache2 Debian Default Page".  Before, it used to be the page that says:

It Works!

This is the default web page for this server. etc...

I'm not sure when this changed, but this debian page is saying "it works" at the top as well.

Anyways, I have my laravel-master folder in this `/var/www` section.  But when I visit:

```
ec2-**-***-***-***.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/laravel-master/
```

I am getting a `Not Found` page.  In the examples I have seen, this should show the directory of files in the `laravel-master` folder.

Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You need to configure Apache with something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel-master
    ServerName mysite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Assuming that all your Laravel files are under `/var/www/laravel-master`. Then put this content in a file: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mylaravel`. (Ubuntu) And run:

```
$ sudo a2dissite default
$ sudo a2ensite mylaravel
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```